# How to turn on my laptop after I pressed Alt-Ctrl-F4

Tags: shortcut-keys, dell-vostro

I have the Black screen with the code.
How I can get back my laptop to normal?

I Just pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>
Then I had this Black screen and it won't let me restart the laptop.

Comment: Ctrl Alt F1 to get back to the login screen or desktop depending on version

Comment: I have a dell vostro 3500 its not working they say sudo my password :

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If you are using a different distribution of Linux which one is it? [Add these information in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1467419/edit)  Take a picture of the screen and add that to the question as well using the "picture" icon above the edit window.

Comment: Which version (and/or flavour) of Ubuntu are you running? Ctrl Alt F1 (press all 3 keys at the same time) works in some [newer] versions, Ctrl Alt F7 works in some [older] versions. But you can also log into the virtual text console (enter user name and then enter password) and work there in text mode. (This is useful if the graphical desktop is failing.)